# Why do added records not show up in SQL Server management studio using SQL Serve Express?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am testing loads of records for my digital music files.

My add routine is:

```
foreach (AlbumModel albumModel in albs)
{
    try
    {
        Album album = GetAlbum(albumModel);
        cmd.CommandText = @"insert into CDS (title,artist,cddbid,genre,tracks,notes)
                            values (@title,@artist,@cddbid,@genre,@tracks,@notes)";

        cmd.Parameters["@title"].Value = album.Title;
        cmd.Parameters["@artist"].Value = album.Artist;
        cmd.Parameters["@cddbid"].Value = album.Id;
        cmd.Parameters["@genre"].Value = album.Genre.First().ToString();
        cmd.Parameters["@tracks"].Value = album.Tracks.Count();
        //cmd.Parameters["@image"].Value = GetCover(album.Title);
        cmd.Parameters["@notes"].Value = GetNotes(album);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.CommandText = @"Select @@Identity";
        var retval = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        string err = e.Message;
    }
}
```

This works fine and I can see the records with a simple load of a datatable.  However, using SQL Server Management Studio and connecting to the same express database on my machine a simple `select * from CDS` doesn't show any records at all.

Am I missing something?

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn))
{
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from CDS order by title", connection))
    {
        adapter.Fill(dt);
    }
}
```

I am not using a transaction.

The connection string is:
     @"Data Source = MyPC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Music;Integrated Security=true"

Which is the exact same one for SSMS.

Comment: you have missed an important point here - how are you connecting to the database? are you attaching the database in your connection string? have you set the mdf/sdf to copy always when you build your project? if so - you are overwriting the data with the existing database.

Comment: I'm not understanding what you are saying.  My connection string is simple 
@"Data Source = MyPC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Music;Integrated Security=true".  And I have not included the data base or connection in my project.  Should I?

Comment: Are you absolutely certain you're connecting to the same database? What does the connection string in your project look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be you open a sql transaction and not commit it. after

```
var retval = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

add this line

```
YourTansaction.Commit();
YourTansaction.Dispose();
YourConnection.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

The classical problem is that you insert the data while using a transaction and you don't commit the transaction. You could try

```
select * from CDS with (READUNCOMMITTED) order by title
```

from the sql management. In that way you can see the uncommitted row in open transactions.

(clearly if that is the problem then you have to modify your code to commit the transaction!)

Comment: xanatos - I am not using the transaction method, just a straight insert.Even after I have waited for a long time, my program shows the records but the query in studio does not show anything.

Answer (score 0):

In Object explorer of the SQL server, navigate to the table you are inserting from the program and right click -> select "Select top 1000 rows". Thanks