# Added rows in apllication not showing in SQL Management Studio

Tags: c#, sql-server-2016-localdb

In my application I am using Entity Framework and I add a row using code similar to this.

```
DatabaseContext.Orders.Add(newOrder);
DatabaseContext.SaveChanges();
```

I checked the database using SQL Management Studio and I could see the new row was there. This was yesterday and so far so good.

Today I loaded my solution and ran it again and added another row.
In my application if I execute the following

```
DatabaseContext.Orders.Count();
```

I get a count of 2, as you would expect, but if I open SQL Management Studio and `Select all` or `select Top 1000`, it only shows 1 row which is the first row I created yesterday.

How is this possible?

My issue is very similar to this post
[Why do added records not show up in SQL Server management studio using SQL Serve Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28779866/why-do-added-records-not-show-up-in-sql-server-management-studio-using-sql-serve)

However the solution does not solve my problem.

I have tried closing down visual studio and restarting it, not sure why but I thought why not.

Also, to check the instances I executed the following line at command prompt

`sqllocaldb info`

and this returned `MSSQLLocalDB`.

Clearly I only have one instance created and this was running.

Oh and just a quick note, I had to reinstall SQLLocalDB 2016 yesterday as for some reason my instance would not start.

EDIT: Just to Add, I delete all the rows in SQL Management Studio. Application still says there are 2 rows

EDITE 2: My connection string from app.config

name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

**UPDATE 1:**
So I decided to delete the instance and recreate it by doing the following.

`sqllocaldb stop MSSQLLocalDB`

`sqllocaldb delete MSSQLLocalDB`

`sqllocaldb create MSSQLLocalDB`

SQL Management Studio now shows zero databases.
I then run my application and it generated the database and tables. SQL Management Studio confirms this.
Now I add rows from my app and I also see them in SQL Management Studio.

I would like to think the issue is solved but I prefer to get an understanding as to what the root of the issue was in the first place.

Comment: Can you share db connection string masking sensitive information?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya added the connection string

Comment: Are you looking at the correct db, Testdb at both application and ssms?

Comment: Yes. The only thing I can think of is that the instance I had issues with yesterday is still somewhere on my system and is working, despite sqllocaldb info only showing the one instance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check you see in SQL Management Studio the same database and table that you worked from your application. Check your connection configuration file.
2. Just for check - add DatabaseContext.Orders.Count() before insertion.
3. May it be another bit of your code that may rewrite data to the old state?

> I have tried closing down visual studio and restarting it,

there is no reason for this

Comment: I have checked the configuration and nothing has changed from yesterday. The code if very simple so there is no issue with point 3 that you mentioned. The only thing I can think of is that the instance I had issues with yesterday is still running and is hidden some how.

Comment: Try to restart the computer. (If you think there is another instance in memory)